# $scope object remains undefined after $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I have an object that returns after `$http.get`. I'm trying to use this object to display in a `clientdetails.html` template page.

```
var app = angular.module('openlegacy', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/main.html',
        controller  : 'clientCtrl'
    })

    .when('/new', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/clientform.html',
        controller  : 'postController'
    })

    .when('/client/:clientid',  {
        templateUrl : 'pages/clientdetails.html',
        controller  : 'clientCtrl'
    })
});

app.controller('clientCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location) {
$scope.oneclient = {};
$scope.getClient = function(clientid) {
    $http({
        method  :   'GET',
        url     :   '/openlegacy/web/client/' + clientid,
        headers :   {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.oneclient = response.data;
            // console.log($scope.oneclient);
            $location.path('/client/' + clientid);
        });
};
```

Here the console.log shows the JSON response object exactly how I want it.

In the `clientdetails.html` I have `<div class="container" ng-controller="clientCtrl">` with a simple `<h1>{{oneclient.name}}</h1>`.

I always get an error that `oneclient` is undefined.

Why is that object undefined ?

The same approach worked perfectly in a `clientlist.html` when I used an `$http.get` to get the list of all clients.

Comment: you sure that http promise is being resolved successfully?

Comment: @Bart K yup, the get returns a perfect JSON object. the console.log if un-commented prints to console the object perfectly.

Comment: Where is the "undefined" error thrown? In the specified code you only set the property, so it should work fine, even the console.log part.

Comment: @Impworks the client list is displayed in a table with clickable rows, that when clicked set the path to the clientdetails. when i reach the clientdetails.html i get the error.

Comment: Why do you use this line: $location.path('/client/' + clientid);

Comment: @MarcusH the getClient(client.id) runs from a clickable row from a table in a different html, so I'm changing the path to the clientdetails.html, with the id of the client I want to display the details of.

Comment: Why `$location.path('/client/' + clientid);`. you can directly access `oneclient` object in your html.

Comment: @RohitJindal I'm not sure I understand the question. I'm changing the path from main.html (where there's a table of all clients, clickable rows) to clientdetails.html (which is supposed to get the client from the `$http.get` and display that clicked client details)

Comment: Ok, So both html uses the clientCtrl. When you load the clientdetails.html it creates a new scope of clientCtrl and it will set the $scope.oneclient = {};. That will result in oneclient.name == undefined.

Comment: So everytime a `<div ng-controller>` calls an angular controller, all the functions in it run ? Is there any way I could fix it and make it work ?

Comment: No. You have to explicitly call the method, either inside of the controller or from the html. If you want to run a function onload, try ng-init="yourfunction".

Comment: @MarcusH Thank you. That solved the issue. You were right, each time the controller "fired" when arriving to the clientdetails.html, the oneclient was reset. I used an init and now it works perfectly. Is it possible to mark a comment as an answer ?

Comment: @maydawn No, A comment can't be marked as the correct answer. I can post the solution as an answer if you accept it?

Comment: @MarcusH sure, go ahead :)

Comment: @maydawn Added answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the method when the controller is instantiated. To run a method onload of the controller, you could use NgInit
 `ng-init="yourfunction()"`

*(Read comments to the main question for more info)*

Be aware that [NgInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) can add some unnecessary logic into the scope.
A cleaner way to call a method whenever the controller is instantiated is to call the method from inside of the controller:

```
$scope.yourfunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without your used routes. But bassicly $scope might be different after you change the route with $location.path().

Comment: try to but a console.log('this is clientCtrl') inside your clientCtrl and you will see that after you change the route the controller logic runs again. so you will again run $scope.oneclient = {}; which leeds to an undefiened name.

Comment: If that's the case, then how come the same approach in the same controller works for getting the entire list of clients?

I'm pretty new to javascript and angularjs, that was a serious question not trying to be sarcastic

Comment: normally you would change the route first and than use something like a clientDetailsCtrl which loads your client.

Comment: And to answer your question i think i again don't have the code to see what you are doing but i think you might not be doing a route change when you are loading your client list in your main view.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Someone helped me in the comments of my original post